# maven works on local but fails on jenkins when working with javascript resources

Tags: javascript, java, maven, jenkins, polymer

I've to compile google polymer resources, and put them into a specific folder, in local (windows 10 with Ubuntu Linux shell integration) works flawlessly, but on my jenkins (which is into a Docker container, on Ubuntu 17.04 Server) it fails.

I'm a newbie with Jenkins, this is my first test with it

The pom configuration is on [GitHub](https://github.com/ITGuy9401/RPGMakerVXtoMVConverterWEB/blob/master/pom.xml)

Here the configuration of the pipeline:

```
node {
   def mvnHome
   def nodeHome
   stage('Preparation') { // for display purposes
      // Get some code from a GitHub repository
      git 'https://github.com/ITGuy9401/RPGMakerVXtoMVConverterWEB.git'
      // Get the Maven tool.
      // ** NOTE: This 'M3' Maven tool must be configured
      // **       in the global configuration.           
      mvnHome = tool 'maven35'
      nodeHome = tool 'nodejs840'
      env.PATH = "${nodeHome}/bin:${mvnHome}/bin:${env.PATH}"
   }
   stage('Build') {

      // Run the maven build
      if (isUnix()) {
         sh "'${mvnHome}/bin/mvn' -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore clean package"
      } else {
         bat(/"${mvnHome}\bin\mvn" -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore clean package/)
      }
   }
   stage('Results') {
      junit '**/target/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml'
      archive 'target/*.jar'
   }
}
```

and there is the console output

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building app 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.6.1:clean (default-clean) @ app ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:exec (clean-web-res) @ app ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:exec (prepare-resource-folder) @ app ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:exec (npm-install) @ app ---
npm WARN polymer-starter-kit@ No repository field.

up to date in 5.152s
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:exec (bower-build) @ app ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:exec (polymer-build) @ app ---
info:    Clearing build/ directory...
info:    (default) Building...
info:    (default) Build complete!
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:exec (test-list-files) @ app ---
bower.json
bower_components
images
index.html
manifest.json
src
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:exec (move-files) @ app ---
cp: cannot stat 'dev-static/build/default/*': No such file or directory
[ERROR] Command execution failed.
org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal(DefaultExecutor.java:404)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute(DefaultExecutor.java:166)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine(ExecMojo.java:804)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine(ExecMojo.java:751)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.execute(ExecMojo.java:313)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:309)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:194)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:993)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:345)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:191)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I've did a lot of attempts to make it works, but nothing was helpful.
Thanks in advice for any help!

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the cause of it all is a typo in your POM:

```
<rgument>
```

instead of

```
<argument>
```

... which occur in several places. Check that out.

My explanation: I suspect that you ran your tests in your Windows 10 PC on a non-clean environment, where a `static` directory already exists, so the goal action that (wrongly) created Directory `static` was silently ignored. But when you tested on a clean environment (the Ubuntu), the `static` directory was not created during the `generate-sources` phase, and then the error arose.

A good practice when building with Maven is to let the `src` directory *as is*. If some file content must be created during the building, it should be generated within the `target` directory. In that way, starting your build with a `clean` is enough to ensure the `target` directory is removed, and the build is started on a clean environment.

And another improvement you could do in your pom is to replace all the `<execution>s` of `exec-maven-plugin` in the `generate-sources` phase by just one which calls one custom script which shall contain the full program:

```
mkdir static
npm install
node_modules/.bin/bower
...
```

In this way, your scripting program becomes more readable.

Comment: Thank you, but why maven didn't print an error for dtd validation?

by the way, after fixing the <rgument typo I've done another run on jenkins but it still print 

    cp: cannot stat 'dev-static/build/default/*': No such file or directory

Comment: Now I'm trying to let it build on jenkins, then I'll do some refactor to maven best practices

Comment: I see. And is it true the error? At the moment the error occurs, there exists the directory `<project>/src/main/resources/dev-static/build/default`, and are there files within it?

Comment: AFAIK, Maven does no DTD validation, because the structure of the POM cannot be determined a priori: It might contain a number of plugins, and each one of them has its own format...

Comment: in theory, this directory exists and has files in it. During test on my local machine I can assert that. polymer-cli creates build/default and inserts into it the index.html plus every js and css file concatenated and compressed.

Comment: Yes, but you must check it _practically_, in the Jenkins environment. Browse the workspace and see if there exists files on that directory.

Answer (score 1):

make sure the settings.xml on your local machine and on Jenkins is the same.

add `-x` to your mvn command so you can see which file you are using